# The data types varchar and varbinary(max) are incompatible in the add operator. while trying to create stored procedure

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

Trying to create a stored procedure in sql server but i'm getting this error. The data types varchar and varbinary(max) are incompatible in the add operator.

```
CREATE PROC dbo.SearchAnswers
    @Name varchar(225),
    @Address varchar(225),
    @ServiceRendered varchar(225),
    @spportedHMO varchar(225),
    @States varchar(225),
    @Country varchar(225),
    @OtherServices varchar(225),
    @Hospital_Image varbinary(225)
AS
SELECT *  
FROM Hospital
WHERE Name LIKE '%' + (@Name) + '%'+'' 
    OR Address LIKE ''+'%' + (@Address) + '%'+'' 
    OR ServiceRendered LIKE ''+'%' + (@ServiceRendered) + '%'+'' 
    OR spportedHMO LIKE ''+'%' + (@spportedHMO) + '%'+'' 
    OR States LIKE '' +'%' + (@States) + '%'+'' 
    OR Country LIKE ''+ '%' + (@Country) + '%'+'' 
    OR OtherServices LIKE ''+'%' + (@OtherServices) + '%'+'' 
    OR Hospital_Image LIKE ''+'%' + Cast(@Hospital_Image as varbinary(max)) + '%'
```

Comment: Why on earth would `@Hospital_Image` be something you can use to search on?

Comment: Totally forgot i don't need it since its not meant to be part of the search input. I have corrected that too. Thanks for the observation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need LIKE wwhen searching Hospital_Image. Change it to '='. Possibly review if you need LIKE for any fields; only use LIKE to search for the string *contained* in the field:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.SearchAnswers
    @Name varchar(225),
    @Address varchar(225),
    @ServiceRendered varchar(225),
    @spportedHMO varchar(225),
    @States varchar(225),
    @Country varchar(225),
    @OtherServices varchar(225),
    @Hospital_Image varbinary(225)
AS
SELECT *  
FROM Hospital
WHERE Name LIKE '%' + (@Name) + '%'+'' 
    OR Address LIKE ''+'%' + (@Address) + '%'+'' 
    OR ServiceRendered LIKE ''+'%' + (@ServiceRendered) + '%'+'' 
    OR spportedHMO LIKE ''+'%' + (@spportedHMO) + '%'+'' 
    OR States LIKE '' +'%' + (@States) + '%'+'' 
    OR Country LIKE ''+ '%' + (@Country) + '%'+'' 
    OR OtherServices LIKE ''+'%' + (@OtherServices) + '%'+'' 
    OR Hospital_Image = @Hospital_Image
```